# What is the best practice for PHP sticky forms?

Tags: php, forms

What is the best or prevailing practice for implementing sticky forms with PHP? Should submitted field data be loaded into the field values from cookies, session variables, or just directly from $_POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whatever you need for your application.

If you need to use the data from the current request, pull it out of `$_POST`.  If you need to hang onto it for multiple requests, use `$_SESSION`.  If it needs to be accessible both client-side and server-side and you don't have a better way of doing it, use `$_COOKIE` (but be wary of size constraints with cookies!).

Comment: "Don't have a better way of doing it" ah so there is precedence. This is what I was wanting to know.

Comment: @reformed No, it's just that there are many ways to send data to the client and a cookie is only one.  This has nothing to do with `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`.  I'm saying that if you can just echo data back to the client rather than setting cookies, you could use that.  None of these methods are the same... they each have their uses.  You must decide the best option based on what it is that you're trying to do.